# How to disable multi touch on UIPangestureRecognizer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a `UICollectionView` to which I have added `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` and `UIPangestureRecognizer` for long press and reordering cells. And also I have added `UIPanGestureRecognizer` for all the `UICollectionViewCells` to show delete and few options on the right side.

My problem is when I pan two `UICollectionViewCells` with two fingers, both the `UICollectionViewCells` are detecting the pan and showing the options.
I want only one of the `UICollectionViewCell` to detect its `UIPangestureRecognizer` at a time. Is there any solution?.

Can anyone please help me out on this?.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable multi touch on collection it self. by making simple property.

```
[UICollectionView setMultipleTouchEnabled:NO];
```

If still problem is not being solve due to Gesture view implementation then you can use `TouchedFlag` for maintain touch on cell.

You can set in

```
- (IBAction) panGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture;
```

You can set `TouchedFlag` to 1 while

```
if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
{
     TouchedFlag=1;
}
```

And set back while `PanGesture` get ended in

```
if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
{
     TouchedFlag=0;
}
```

So your finale code should look like

```
- (IBAction) panGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{

    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan && TouchedFlag==0)
    {
        TouchedFlag=1;
        //Do your PAN openration
    }
    else if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan && TouchedFlag==1) {
        //just prompt msg to user then single view at a time allowd to PAN
    }
    else if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        TouchedFlag=0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried the [minimumNumberOfTouches](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPanGestureRecognizer_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIPanGestureRecognizer/minimumNumberOfTouches) / [maximumNumberOfTouches](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPanGestureRecognizer_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIPanGestureRecognizer/maximumNumberOfTouches) property of UIPangestureRecognizer?